# Using CSS multi-column layout leaves unwanted top and bottom margin

Tags: html, css, css-multicolumn-layout

I'm experimenting with CSS3 columns, and I noticed there are top and bottom margins added, despite that I explicitly set them to 0. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

I've highlighted the margins in yellow. The red rectangles are block level element outlines drawn from the Web Developer Toolbar add-on in Firefox.

Here's my CSS:

```css
.section .content {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 26px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

How can I get rid of the margins?

Upon request uploaded my code to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufobax/1/edit). It also shows the discrepancy between the tops for the two columns. The margin doesn't show when I don't use columns.

Comment: @Michael - Seems to be down. I first got a "500 Internal server error", but now iidrn.com confirms it is down.

Comment: jsFiddle is down, try this http://jsbin.com/ ..... are you sure that that margin isn't a margin bottom from the h1? What happens if you remove your column css, do you still see that margin?

Comment: @Cadence - I added a link to my code on jsbin. The margin doesn't show if I don't use columns. So it's not a marging from h1 (which would also show the margin for the second coumn, IMO). Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is very simple, you are adding CSS to content, but content contains a paragraph with a margin. Reset it to 0.

```css
p {
    margin:0
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <div class="content">
        <p>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/ufobax/2/edit

Comment: +1  Aargh! That was probably too easy, and that's why I overlooked it :-).  (I'll probably accept as well, but I tend to wait a day, allowing other answers too, which may give additional info.)

Comment: @stevenvh did you perhaps forget to click the checkmark here? :-)